# How to get client to recognise object class contained in EJB project?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

I have created project with an EJB and remote interface as shown below. I also have created a class to hold an object (ShipData) in this project. I deploy this bean to the server. I then created a class with a main method in a new Dynamic project as shown below also, where I inject the bean that I created. The problem seems to be that the class ShipData is not being recognised. Can anyone tell me if they can see something fundamentally wrong with what I have done. I have shown my file structures for both the server and client projects as well. Thanks for any help.

### EJB

```
@Stateless
public class ShipBean implements ShipBeanRemote {

private ShipData newShip;
private List<ShipData> listOfShips;

public void addShip(String shipName,int tonnage,String nationality){
    newShip=new ShipData(shipName, tonnage, nationality);
    listOfShips.add(newShip);

}

public ShipData searchShip(String shipName){
    for(int i=0; i<listOfShips.size(); i++){
        if(listOfShips.get(i).getShipName() != null && listOfShips.get(i).getShipName().equals(shipName));
           newShip=listOfShips.get(i);
    }
    return newShip;
}
}
```

### Remote Interface

```
@Remote
public interface ShipBeanRemote {

public void addShip(String shipName,int tonnage,String nationality);


public ShipData searchShip(String shipName);

}
```

### Ship Data

```
public class ShipData{

private String shipName;
private int tonnage;
private String nationality;

public ShipData(String shipName, int tonnage, String nationality) {
    this.shipName = shipName;
    this.tonnage = tonnage;
    this.nationality = nationality;
}

public String getShipName() {
    return shipName;
}

public void setShipName(String shipName) {
    this.shipName = shipName;
}

public int getTonnage() {
    return tonnage;
}

public void setTonnage(int tonnage) {
    this.tonnage = tonnage;
}

public String getNationality() {
    return nationality;
}

public void setNationality(String nationality) {
    this.nationality = nationality;
}

}
```

### class in new project with main method and EJB injection

```
public class SearchShips {

@EJB (lookup="java:global/ShippingBeans/ShipBean") 
 private ShipBeanRemote ship; 
 /* calculator is the representative of the bean, created 
 at runtime using dependency injection */ 


public static void main (String[] args){

    printAnabellaInfo();
}

public void printAnabellaInfo(){
ship.addShip("shipA",10,"Irish");
ship.addShip("Anabella",15,"French");
ship.addShip("shipC",12,"English");


ship.searchShip("Anabella");
System.out.println(ship.getShipName);

}
}
```

[image: File Structure of both projects]

Answer (score 1):

ShipData is an Model/Data bean/Data transfer object. Move it to another project (may be call it as commonComponents or DataObjects). Now create jar out of that project and place it in the classpath for the client and the server(EJB) projects.

In ypur current setup the ShipData object will be exposed only to the server (EJB project).

Comment: If I place ShipData class as a nested class within the EJB, ShipBean class, would it solve my problem? I have tried doing it like that but it's still not working (but seems to me that it should) so was just wondering if you had any thoughts on that approach. Thanks

Comment: Having it as a nested object will expose ShipData only to Server. you can create a seperate project for the objects thats used both in server and client(1) or you need to duplicate the code in both server and client(2). Option 1 is the best.